# Elastic Search nearest distinct geo locations

Tags: elasticsearch

I created the following mapping to index my mysql collection:

```
    "properties" : {
       "post_place_location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
       }
    }
```

How do I retrieve the nearest distinct docs?

Comment: Use the Geo distance query

Comment: Geo distance query doesn't give distinct it only gives nearest locations.suppose I need first 100 nearest locations. in First 100 each location is repeated save for 10 Times. Then  First 100 locations will contain only 10. it is exact problem .

Comment: Maybe wrap it in top hits aggregation with size 1 to return distinct locations?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your index is called `locs` and your `geo_point` field is called `location`, you can use the following:

```
GET locs/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "20km",
            "location": {
              "lat": 48.19735694026487,
              "lon": 16.38336181640625
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "doc['location'].getValue();"
        }
      }
    },
    "terms_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "doc['location'].getValue();"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_hits_agg": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```